# Linux delay command until after an older process completes

Tags: linux, command-line

I'd like to be able to launch a command now, but have it start only after an older command (which is already running) completes.

For example, say I'm copying a large file over the network, an action that already saturates my network bandwidth. I then want to copy a second large, less important file to the same destination, but in order for the first copy to finish asap I'd like to delay this second copy until after the first finished.

Normally I would do this:

10 minutes ago:
`cp large_file_urgent ~/networkmnt/`
Present time:
`sleep <some_guesstimated_time_for_old_cp_to_finish> && cp large_file_lessimportant ~/networkmnt`

Is there a smarter way to do this? Can I somehow tell the second `cp` to wait until the first `cp`'s PID terminates?

This is on Ubuntu 13.04 (in case that's of any consequence).

Comment: i think kill -0 is perhaps what you are looking for. just loop it and once the loop exits, your second cp can run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know in advance the commands you need to run, you can just do

```
cp file1 file2; cp file3 file4
```

If you have already started the first command, and you are in the same shell, you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, then [`bg`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#index-bg) to put the first command in the background, then call [`wait`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#index-wait) on the job number or PID to wait until it finishes. For example:

```
$ sleep 30
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 30
$ bg
[1]+ sleep 30 &
$ wait %1; echo "next command"
[1]+  Done                    sleep 30
next command
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cp largefile1 somedestination
```

...time...passes...

```
wait $(pidof cp)
cp largefile2 someplace
```

The bash builtin wait, will pause until the job/process specified (or all jobs if unspecified) has completed before continuing.

Comment: There is also a [wait](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1/wait/) command that does the same thing (excluding shell jobs, of course).

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the process is still running using the `/proc` filesystem:

```
while test -d /proc/$cp_pid; do
  sleep 10
done 
cp next_big_file network
```

Comment: It fails if the PID gets reused in the pause between checks.